# I know to update a particular fields value in an embedded object in MongoDB using Node.js. Suppose my database structure is

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mlab

I know to update a particular fields value in an embedded object in MongoDB using Node.js. Suppose my database structure is

```
"Lemon Soda": [
        {
            "RecipeName": "Lemon Soda"
            "Likes": 121
        }
       ]
```

So I can use the update function to update the 'Likes' value which is inside the embedded array "Lemon Soda" like : `

```
 db.collection(db_collection).update(
                {"Lemon Soda.RecipeName": db_recipe},
                {$set: {"Gasbased.Likes": "122"}}, function (err, results) {
                    console.log("likes updated" + count);
                    console.log(results);
                }
            )
`
```

where 'db_collection' is a variable which stores the collection name and 'db_recipe' which stores "Lemon Soda".
Now suppose I have 'Lemon Soda' in a variable called 'db_recipe'and I want to change/update the field 'Likes' which is inside 'Lemon Soda' embedded array using 'db_recipe' instead of `"Lemon Soda.RecipeName": db_recipe`.
How can I do that because we cant use a varible in our query like

```
{"[db_recipe].RecipeName": db_recipe}
```

Regards,
Shiven

Comment: On the NodeJS side you can.

Comment: Okay BankysySan but, how?? I will be a great help to me if you could tell me how to update it.